# Does the word "Yahoo" have a verb meaning?

Tags: word-usage, verb-usage

Reading [this article](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-57253947), I noticed a fun expression saying, "DO YOU, UH. YAHOO?" 
 [image] Checking it on the Internet, I found several sites quoting the wording. From the context in the article, what it means seems like "Do you still use Yahoo?" If this is correct, do you use the word "Yahoo" as a verb?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo_(Gulliver%27s_Travels)

Comment: I believe there have actually been *several* publications titled [***Do you Facebook**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22do+you+facebook%22) We can "verbify" just about any noun in English - including proper nouns such as ***Facebook*** and ***Yahoo*** (which it's easy to ***google*** examples of, and you can decide for yourself whether to capitalise any given instance of a verbified proper noun).

Comment: But in the cited example above, it's worth noting ***UH*** - which is essentially equivalent to enclosing the following term in "scare quotes" to alert the reader that what's coming next pushes the boundaries of traditional grammar and/or semantics (not becaiuse there's anything *wrong* with doing this; it's just a courtesy to the reader, to help him parse the text without having to struggle).

Comment: Someone voted to close this question as being prone to create "opinion based" answers.  I disagree-- the concept and tradition of "verbifying" nouns is quite concrete and can provide a clear answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, but sort of yes. Yahoo is not a verb, except to the extent that any noun can be used as a verb.

There is a particular pattern in english of the form "do/did you [noun]?" where the speaker is asking whether you have interest, ability, or experience in using the noun, particularly in an unusual manner. This is called "verbing", the practice of using a noun as a verb, and originated from slang but has become fairly widespread. See also "buffy speak".